# Laravel commenting with ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5.6

So I have a laravel commenting system which lets me conment using ajax. My current setup is simple. I have a field for comments and then my route is as follows:

```
Route::post(‘comment/{post_id}’, ‘CommentController@insert’);
```

And in my ajax url, I have given the same route with the `post_id`. I am giving the post id because I wanted to add the post id to my `post_id` column in my comments table. Also my ajax is in line.

Now my question is, I do not know how to add replies to a comment. I have to insert the `comment_id` to my replies table comment_id column because comment and replies are related. What confuses me is, if I created a lot of reply forms with a foreach loop for each comment, how can I pass all those comment ID to the ajax?
Say for an example this is my route for storing replies

```
Route::post(‘replies/{comment_id}’, ‘ReplyController@insert’);
```

This won’t be like comments that I will be passing only value for the parameter (post_id). This reply will have a lot of values for one parameter right? So how can I proceed with this. I am new to ajax and I am having a hard time trying to get the logic of this. Like I mentioned before, the confusion is that each reply will have a separate comment_id that I need to pass to the route parameter.

Comment: you are not giving `post_id` in route but in request . so share your ajax request ?

Answer (score 1):

you should pass like below:

```
Route::post('/comment/{comment_id}/replies','ReplyController@insert');
```

Comment: This one i get. But can you help me with the ajax. How do i write the url of ajax request? I mean, each comment has many replies right? So how can i tell ajax which comment_id i am passing? that bit is confusing.

Comment: pass data-url from view like:data-url="/comment/{{$comment->id}}/replies" then get it in js file like

Comment: var url = $(this).attr('data-url'); and put var url into the url section of ajax.

Comment: So just to clarify, data-url= goes to form, correct? So i loop replies forms and use data-url in each form outputting the comment id.

Comment: Ok so how would the form look like then? What will the action be on form? Method is a post. What about action? And i will just have to place the data-url on the comment div?

Comment: Your using ajax so there is no need to add form tag. you can directly fetch the data-url using the .attr in your js file

Comment: check i have added an answer, how the form should look and where to call ajax

Comment: also you can pass your data like data-reply

Comment: remove <form> and <button> from view file.

Comment: add <input name="reply" data-url="/comment/{{$comment->id}}/replies"/>

Comment: So the “insert reply” button. How would it know where to go without form? Shall i write a onclick prevent default and go to a specified route()? Sorry if i sound like i complete noob. I just have a hard time understanding ajax and how to perform calls

Comment: in javascript file use var url = $(this).attr('data-url'); and try console.log(url);

Comment: @PICKAB00 i have added answer below, you can try

Comment: this is ajax it works on url why you need a button over there.

Comment: Yes i do understand that. But shouldn’t there be a button to submit? The user must be able to click a button right? How else would they post it?

Comment: @rkj yes i have seen your answer. And i will give that a try too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

**View** (here `$comments` and `$comment->replies` are assumed, you may have different)

```
<div class="post-comments">
    <p>Comments</p>
     @foreach($comments as $comment)
        <p>{{$comment->text}}<p>

        <label>Replies:</label>
        <ul>
          @foreach($comment->replies as $reply)
            <li>{{$reply->text}}</li>
          @endforeach
           <form name="replyForm">
               <input name="reply" />
               <button type="button" onclick="replyComment('/comment/{{$comment->id}}/reply', this.form.reply)">Reply</button>
          </form>
        </ul>
     @endforeach
  </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function replyComment(url, input){

   console.log(url);
   console.log(input.value);
   //call ajax with this url and input value
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('comment/{comment_id}/reply', 'ReplyController@insert);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-primary" value="Comment" id="comment" data-url="/comment/{{$comment->id}}/replies" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" data-comment_id="{{$comment->id}}" >
```

assuming that you are fetching the $comment from controller.
even if you are adding button there is no need to add the `<form>`.

Comment: So now all that is required is to give two input tags. Name of the user and Reply. Yes?

Comment: @PICKAB00 user id you can get it from auth, no need to add it in form, did you try my answer

Comment: Currently away from pc. Will try as soon as i get back

Comment: @rkj sorry let me explain. The whole concept is for guests to be able to add comments and reply to comments. That is why i said user name. So I wouldn’t need auth() in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `post_id` during reply .

Route like :

```
Route::`post(‘replies/{post_id}/{comment_id}’, ‘ReplyController@insert’);`
```

Then sort it those comment by inserting time .

Comment: Sorry but what I wanted to know was how I could pass comment_id. I mean, in one post, there will be many comments right? How can i tell ajax that this reply belongs to a specific comment? In other words, how can i tell ajax which comment this reply is going to? Each comment will have an id right? What should i put in ajax url?